# How to use Apache Felix from my Java code? how to add maven POM code?

Tags: java, apache-felix

I want to start Felix in embedded mode. I want to do this with a maven build.

What maven do I need to add to my pom.xml to allow Felix to run in embedded mode?

What code do I need to add to my application?

Thanks, Philip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html